# Need Directions In Creating Timeline In HTML CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css

I would like to know how can I make a timeline. I want to make a timeline like this:-

http://www.charitywater.org/projects/approach/

Can anyone tell me how this website is making such a vertical line and dot? I can't seem to figure it out.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbYWm.png

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately, your question is a bit too broad - there are many was of achieving this effect.

SO isn't a 'give me the code plz' website; you need to show a little effort on your part if you want people to help. Have you tried looking at the source code for the page in question, and replicating it yourself?

Comment: @MassivePenguin The problem is I can't figure out exactly which element is responsible for vertical lines and dots. I don't want code. I just want to know which element is responsible for rendering these two parts and how they are able to do so. Thank you.

Comment: As Ruben states (below), the orange line is a CSS3 pseudo-element declared on the `approach-section` element. Not sure why his answer was downvoted, as it's correct.

Answer (score 0):

Black dot is being created  using :before CSS3 pseudoelements:

```
.timeline-block:before {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #000000;
    border: 5px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 50%;
    bottom: 0;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 10px;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 10px;
}
```

And orange line using :after pseudoelements

```
.approach-section:after {
    background: url("/projects/images/end-timeline-drop.png") repeat scroll 0 0 / cover rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    bottom: -64px;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 66px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -13px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 25px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

About pseudo elements : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements